# How to make one word in a line of text a bit higher or lower than other words?

Tags: html, css

I wonder if there is a way to make one word in a line of text a bit higher or lower than other words?

[image]

```
<p>what is this life if <span class="higher">full of care</span> we have <span class="lower">no time</span> to stand and stare</p>
```

I tried to add "display: inline-flex;" and insert pseudo elements after these spans. Unfortunately it just adds pseudo element under the span and doesn't move the text inside span.

```
.higher{
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.higher:after{
    content: "";
    height: 5px;
    width: 10px;
}
```

But please let me make two conditions:

1) I know about  and  tags (as well as "vertical-align: sub;" and "vertical-align: sup;" styles) but they don't allow to fine tune offsets.

2) That would be great to get a solution for multi-line text.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Y u no use `transform: translateY` instead of all this flex and pseudo-element stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Kosh Very](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5724303/kosh-very) I found the solution:

```
.higher{
    transform: translate(0, -5px);
}
.lower{
    transform: translate(0, 5px);
}
```